# Query error printing data many times MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My query is working, and when I call the tables it works correctly, however, the display is overly printing the second foreach loop. I have tried to use a for loop to correct this, but it doesn't work. Anyone have any suggestions on how to use the second table without displaying it's column multiple times? Thanks!

View:

```
        @foreach (ModelA modela in Model.ModelA)
        {
                DateTime CurrTime = DateTime.Now;
                    if (modela.LastUpdate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10))
            { 
            <tr>
                <td>@modela.Keys</td>
                <td>@modela.IDs</td>

                <td>

                    @foreach (ModelB modelb in Model.ModelB) {

                            if (modela.IDs != null)
                            {
                            @modelb.DisplayName
                            }     
                    }
                </td> 
            </tr>

            }
            }

    </table>
</font>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a nested loop:

```
foreach (ModelA modela in Model.ModelA) {
    // print something
    foreach (ModelB modelb in Model.ModelB) {
        // print something
    }
}
```

So the collection in `Model.ModelB` is going to be printed, in its entirety, repeatedly for each element in the collection in `Model.ModelA`.  If you only want to print it once, only loop over it once:

```
foreach (ModelA modela in Model.ModelA) {
    // print something
}
foreach (ModelB modelb in Model.ModelB) {
    // print something
}
```

Comment: When I use this, the columns display below each other instead of next to each other.

Comment: @Bee: You're going to have to either modify the HTML markup/styling or modify the logic you're using to print values in the first place.  I don't know what you're trying to do, but the reason you're seeing the results multiple times is because that's what your nested loop is doing.